# "-10 User was removed"?

Tags: discussion

So I just noticed in my reputation change listing the following item: "-10
User was removed".

What does this indicate? Is the idea that there was a user who upvoted an answer of mine but who has since had his account deleted?

Comment: I've no idea! That's wild :)

Comment: Ask on meta.SO or any popular SE chat. I just tried to join the admin/mod chat to ask but some auth issues prevented me from logging in... Sorry!

Comment: No worries, it's just a curiosity. I'll ask over at meta.SO.

Comment: At least one user in the meta.SO chat says it's because a user upvoted one of my answers and later had his account deleted. I'm content, mystery solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're exactly right. When an account is deleted, all of that account's upvotes and downvoted are deleted as well.

A good thread about this, and some of its ups and downs, can be found at [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125740/205676).